# Ansible - Append Item to List that's Buried within Dictionary

Tags: list, ansible, nested, append, yaml

### Objective

I am trying to append a string to a list belonging to a key which is a few layers down within a dictionary.

---

### Explanation

I initialize an empty list buried within some pre-existing variable called info:

```
tasks:

  - set_fact:
      info: "{{ info | combine( { host: { repo: { folders: [] }}}, recursive=true ) }}"
```

In a later task, I wish to append a string to that empty list. This may happen over multiple tasks, so I don't want to replace the empty list, but add onto it as needed. I am currently trying this:

```
tasks:

  - set_fact:
      info: "{{ info | combine( { 'host': { 'repo': { 'folders': [] }}}, recursive=true ) }}"


  - set_fact:
      info: "{{ info.host.repo.folders + ['ERROR. folderX does not exist'] }}"
    when: folderX does not exist
  - set_fact:
      info: "{{ info.host.repo.folders + ['ERROR. folderY does not exist'] }}"
    when: folderY does not exist
```

However, I receive a template error:

```
FAILED! => {"msg": "template error while templating string: expected name or number. String: {{ info.host.repo.folder + ['ERROR. folderX does not exist'] }}"}
```

I know that you can simply add elements to a list when the destination is on topmost layer. For example:

```
- set_fact:
    folders: []
- set_fact:
    folders: "{{ folders + ['ERROR. folderX does not exist'] }}"
  when: folderX does not exist
- set_fact:
    folders: "{{ folders + ['ERROR. folderY does not exist'] }}"
  when: folderY does not exist

- debug: var=folders
```

Which, as desired, gives:

```
TASK [debug] ***************************************************************************************************
"folders": [
    "ERROR. folderX does not exist",   
    "ERROR. folderY does not exist"
]
```

So, how does the syntax change when I am trying to descend multiple layers and access a list that resides in a nested dictionary? Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

`dict`s and `list`s in ansible are "live", so you can update them via `set` statements

```yaml
- set_fact:
    info: >-
      {%- set _ = info.host.repo.update({"folders": []}) -%}
      {{ info }}
- set_fact:
    info: >-
      {%- set _ = info.host.repo.folders.append("ERROR. folderY does not exist") -%}
      {{ info }}
  when: folderY does not exist
```

*that `set _ =` business is because ansible's jinja does not support the `do` statement so one cannot have an assignment statement by itself*